# Making Generic Linked list placing next pointer at beginning of structure

Tags: c++, generics, linked-list

I am reading one of the books and stuck at one particular question.

Definition of a struct for linked list :::

```
typedef struct LinkedList{
  LinkedList* next;
  int data;
}
```

Book says "Placing the next pointer at the beginning of the structure or class makes it easy to write generic list-handling routines no matter what the data holds."

I am not able to understand how placing the next pointer on top will help here.

Also, to make a generic list, wouldn't we need the data type as generic or say void*?

Comment: If this definition is taken 1:1 from a C++ book, then the book sucks. This could be a possible explanation of the assertion that you are questioning.

Comment: Where do you see this? The statement you've printed here only makes sense if the author were doing something that would be easier with inheritance or templates. On its face, that line doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Are you *sure* that this is a C++ book? That looks a lot like C code...

Comment: That would be too extreme to say Sir Rudolph. I don't know how good the writer is about his cooncepts but sureshot it is the best book to start for preparation for interviews. Book name is Interviews Exposed.

Comment: Cody, This is more of a interview book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book you're looking at, *Programming Interviews Exposed*, is (as far as I can tell) *not* a book on C++, but rather a book meant to prepare you to answer the kinds of questions that might be asked at a typical technical interview. I wouldn't take anything in the book as a best C++ practice unless it's labelled as such (and perhaps not even then).

The advice to put the next pointer first in a linked list node structure comes from languages like C, where you can't rely on real, compiler-supported inheritance. The idea is, in fact, to implement something like inheritance yourself by piggybacking data onto the linked list node structure. Consider:

```
typedef struct LinkedList {
  LinkedListNode* next;
  int type;
}

typedef struct Person {
  LinkedList listNode;
  char name[64];
  int age;
}

typedef struct Address {
  LinkedList listNode;
  char streetAddress[128];
  char city[32];
  char state[2];
  char zip[10];
}

typedef struct Employee {
  Person person;
  int department;
  int salary;
}
```

LinkedList here is a base type -- not good for much by itself, but useful as a starting point for nodes with more data. You don't have to know anything about the other types in order to perform linked list operations on a node... you can cast any node pointer to LinkedList* and access the information you need. So, you can have a list of Person and list of Address, and both can be manipulated with the same set of routines. Likewise, you can cast a Employee* to a Person* and use any operations that you've written for Person on Employee as well. If you assign appropriate constants to LinkedList's `type` field, you can even mix PersonNode and use the `type` field to determine the type of each node later.

This was a useful way to program 20+ years ago. It still works, of course, but most people would choose to let the compiler manage inheritance for them if they have the option, and all modern object-oriented langauges do offer that option.

**Lesson:** Understand the technique in case you come across it in old code, but choose a different implementation for your new code if you can.

Comment: thanks Caleb. Understood the well explained answer and problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you place the next pointer at the beginning, and all you have is a void*, but you know it's a linked list node, you can always find the next pointer. This is in contrast to the next pointer being placed after the 'data', assuming 'data' can be of different sizes, you'd need to know more about the object in order to find the next pointer

Comment: your code snippet looks more like C than C++, so that's what I assumed you're working with. If it's C++, I'd suggest tossing the book

Comment: I get your point and it makes some sense, but the book says that data type is int, which increases the confusion

Comment: Your quote says "makes it easy to write generic list-handling routines **no matter what the data holds**"  -- so it sounds like their point is to realize that the technique is flexible enough to handle the contained data being of any type

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not see any reason, and I agree, the argument should be templated:

```
template <class T> class ListElement
{
   T data;
   ListElement* next;
   ...
}
```

There may be some issues regarding speed with memory alignment being a bit better the other way round, but I doubt this!

hth

Mario

Comment: Your snippet makes sense to me but it still doesn't answer the question?

Comment: My answer is that the book doesn't make sense. and as others pointed out, the code much of C++, especially if templates are used in the same paragraph